# Php run xcodebuild cannot find provisioning profile

Tags: php, ios, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

I wanna run a server to build ipa for me.When it comes to use Xcode to build app use these command:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/xxxx/sites/PhpServer/AutoUpload/ProjectsDir/48c36d185970fa9231f1f6274b72cf60/48c36d185970fa9231f1f6274b72cf60.xcodeproj -target 48c36d185970fa9231f1f6274b72cf60 -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It turn out to be:

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings
```

I've checked in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning profile`,the provisioning profile lay there well.

What I am confused about is that it runs well in terminal from the same directory where the Server root is.

What I am thinking is that maybe the `xcodebuild` execution from php cannot find the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning profile` directory.

1. How can I specify the location path of provisioning profile when using `xcodebuild`,`PROVISIONING_PROFILE=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` by only specify the ID, how about the location path?
2. Is there any other methods to get through `Building ipa`?

Comment: Cleanup formatting and grammar

Comment: Hi @Johnny_mess I am also facing same problem , Can you please give guidance how to resolve the above issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve the problem.I yelled out ‘finally...’.

This is because when u double click the .cer file to install,the system install .cer file under the 'login' category.what u need to do is open key chain app to move .cer file from 'login' to 'system' category.